# optaplanner benchmark file in xml format for VRP

Tags: optaplanner

We have our input file in xml format which is described in "unsolved" directory of optaplanner examples.

when we are using benchmark config file it is using ".vrp" format. Anyway we could change that to understand the xml format? Attached is xml config file that I am changing and want to use ".xml" instead of ".vrp" file format. Any suggestions?

```
<problemBenchmarks>
<solutionFileIOClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.persistence.VehicleRoutingFileIO</solutionFileIOClass>
  <inputSolutionFile>data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium/basic/air/belgium-n50-k10.vrp</inputSolutionFile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xStreamAnnotatedClass>` instead of `<solutionFileIOClass>`. See `cloudBalancingBenchmarkConfig.xml`.